# Make LinkedIn oauth2 call from localhost using PHP

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make LinkedIn Plugin which fetch users profile. I'm using REST API for that purpose, but when i make call from localhost it shows following error

```
Simple-LinkedIn: library not compatible with installed PECL OAuth extension. Please disable this extension to use the Simple-LinkedIn library.
```

please guide me.

[index file](http://pastebin.com/0Hmd1WMJ)

[oauth file](http://pastebin.com/nFWZMgG7)

In both file only key values are changed.

I'm using XAMPP server on my window 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two options.

First, you can follow the suggestion in the message above, and uninstall the PECL oauth module that conflicts with the Simple-LinkedIn library. PECL exstensions cna be uninstalled via:

```
pecl uninstall xxx
```

Where xxx is the module.

Secondly, you can use the already installed oauth module to make the LinkedIn calls. Details on making the calls using this library can be found on the LinkedIn Developers site:

[https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/reading-data#toggleview:id=php](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/reading-data#toggleview%3aid=php)
[https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/writing-linkedin-apis#toggleview:id=php](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/writing-linkedin-apis#toggleview%3aid=php)